# Spring security Dynamic authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

im using spring security and spring boot to develop an application, to protect a specific endpoint of my api im using a SecurityConf as follows:

```
 @Override
public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .inMemoryAuthentication()
    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
    .withUser(username).password(password).roles(ADMIN_ROLE);
}

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/survey/report/**").hasRole(ADMIN_ROLE)
    .and().formLogin()
    .and().logout();
}
```

the password and username are loaded from a DB at **start**.

everything seemed to work fine, but now i have to implement a method to change the admin's password, i implemented the repository, service and controller methods to change the DB with the new encrypted password, but as it stands now, the changes doesn't get reflected in the application unless i restart it (which causes the class to load the new username and password).

how can i make the application **reload** the new username and password from the database without having to restart it? (in production this is an application which will run without stopping)

this is the controller for the password change method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/change", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity changePassword(@RequestBody Password password) {

    return passwordService.updatePassword(password);
}
```

and this is the service method:

```
public ResponseEntity updatePassword(Password password) {
    Administrator administrator = administratorRepository.findAdministrator();
    if (passwordEncoder.matches(password.getOldPassword(), administrator.getPassword())) {
        String encodePassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password.getNewPassword());
        administrator.setPassword(encodePassword);
        administratorRepository.updateAdministrator(administrator);

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

### edit

i load the username and password on atributes of the SecurityConfig class with an Autowired method like this:

```
@Autowired
private void initUser() {
    Administrator administrator = administratorRepository.findAdministrator();
    this.password = administrator.getPassword();
    this.username = administrator.getUsername();

}
```

and my class is defined as this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String ADMIN_ROLE = "ADMIN";

private String username;
private String password;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
private AdministratorRepository administratorRepository;
```

passwordencoder is a class that i use to salt and hash the admin pass, the repo is where i persist the data

Comment: Surely not the most effective way but you could force the logout by forcing the redirect to `/logout`.

Comment: logout doesnt refresh the user in the application, i will still have to access using the old username and password (the changes are in the db but not in the app)

Comment: How do you load the username and password from DB? You should refresh them into memory when change the password.

Comment: how do i refresh them into memory is exactly what im asking xD

Comment: you will create UserDetailService and return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User() and use your password

Comment: Btw this is not spring security dynamic 'authorization' but spring security dynamic 'authentication'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CustomUserDetailService instead of AuthenticationProvider like this

```
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {


    private static String username;
    private static String password;
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {



        return new User(CustomUserDetailsService.username,CustomUserDetailsService.password,null);
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Inject
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

    }

}
```

and then change password in

```
public ResponseEntity updatePassword(Password password) {
    Administrator administrator = administratorRepository.findAdministrator();
    if (passwordEncoder.matches(password.getOldPassword(), administrator.getPassword())) {
        String encodePassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password.getNewPassword());
        administrator.setPassword(encodePassword);
        administratorRepository.updateAdministrator(administrator);
        CustomUserDetailsService.password=encodePassword;
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: woah thanks!, just one question:
wouldn't returning a new user (in the userDetailsService) make that there are consistently more admins authorized?

Comment: another clarification (sorry i still have a ton to learn xD) if i wanted to create another admin i would have to implement another method?

Comment: i think you will manage user in database .when your application restart new password lose .